# AWS Cognito and API Gateway for a RESTful API

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I would like to build a RESTful API that will be used by a mobile app. We have decided to go for AWS.

I would like to implement a micro service for sign-in/sign-up using the API Gateway. Is their a way to use cognito behind the AWS Api Gateway ? I would like to create a lambda to sign-in users using Cognito. I want to do that to build a complete REST Api and by doing that avoid using any Cognito SDK.

Can you explain if it is possible and if so can someone show me how to proceed ?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html should help. You'll still need to use the sdk to get the authentication token on signin.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a Lambda function behind API Gateway endpoint, to receive cognito user credentials and [authenticate](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html) using Cognito SDK. The response tokens from cognito authenticateUser methods needs to be sent back to your mobile client to invoke other API Gateway endpoints.